# How to Stop IIS Website on muliple Servers using checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, iis, checkedlistbox

I have a winform that can stop and start IIS website remotely however I'm looking for a way to stop/start website on muliple servers by using checkedlistbox. Here's my Stop IIS website code

```
   private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serverName = textServer.Text;
        string siteName = cmbWebsite.SelectedItem.ToString();


        using (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager sm = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName))
        {

            Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site site = sm.Sites.Where(q => q.Name.Equals(siteName)).FirstOrDefault();
            // If the site does not exist, throw an exception       
            if (site == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("The specified site was not found!");
            }
            // Stop the site        
            site.Stop();
            showStatus(siteName);

        }
    }
```

I wanted to be able to run this on multiple servers so instead of putting the server (textServer) on the text box. User can just check on which server/server they wanted to stop.

Any assistance is greatly apprecieated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
using (Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager sm = Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName))
{
   foreach(var server in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
   {
      try
      {
        Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site site = sm.Sites.Where(q => q.Name.Equals(server.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();      
        site.Stop();
        showStatus(siteName);
      }
      catch(Exception e) { /*handle*/ }
   }
}
```

you just want to loop through the items

Comment: I tried the code but it doesn't work. I'm trying to run the site.Stop on remote servers. The ServerManager.OpenRemote(serverName)) is looking for parameters that are not initialized until the foreach command. Any ideas?